# Core data + localization

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple Core Data Entity "Task to perform" that contains Attribute of type String.
`Core Data` model is prepopulate from file under first app launch, and "Task to perform" attributes contains folllowing values:
Run, Walk, Sleep etc.

I want to localize "Task to perform" attributes in different languages, Fr, Es. But I don't understand how to

1. How to correctly save inside `Core Data` localized attributes for 3 languages (en, fr, es)?
2. How to fetch localized attributes from Core Data. For exp. if phone language set to France return "courir" insted of "Run"?

Comment: Save the key of the localization, it's like a "type". Retrieve it, and show it to user using `let stringToShow = NSLocalizedString("attributedFromCoreDataName", "")` Or add an extension to translate the "key" for CoreData into the key that is in `Localizable.strings`

Comment: I am new in core data. Can you pls explain what needs to be done in more detail?

Comment: Do you know how to use localization strings at least?

Comment: Yes. I already localized my UI elements and variables.

Comment: Then just save a close range of strings in Core Data. The translation should be done outside of CoreData

Comment: If I correctly understand I need: 1) prepolulate core data with one language, 2) translate core data attributes inside Localizable.strings, 3) Retrieve it using NSLocalizedString. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Save into CoreData "keys", a "closed" set of keys, like:
`"Run"`, `"Walk"`, `"Sleep"`.

In your *Localizable.strings*:

English:

```
"SomeKeyForRun" = "Run";
"SomeKeyForWalk" = "Walk";
"SomeKeyForSleep" = "Sleep";
```

French:

```
"SomeKeyForRun" = "Courir";
"SomeKeyForWalk" = "Marcher";
"SomeKeyForSleep" = "Dormir";
```

etc.

Create an extension for your entities and add it a method/computed var

```
extension MyCoreDataEntity {
    func localizedActivityName() -> String {
         switch(myCoreDataEntityProperty) {
            case "Run":
                return NSLocalizedString("SomeKeyForRun")
            case "Walk":
                return NSLocalizedString("SomeKeyForWalk")
            case "Sleep":
                return NSLocalizedString("SomeKeyForSleep")
            default:
                return myCoreDataEntityProperty //or "Unknown Activity" etc.
         }
    }
}
```

When you want to show the activity:

```
let activityLocalized: String = myCoreDataEntity.localizedActivityName()
```

In case of too many cases, you can decide on a pattern for the construction of the key and do so in the *Localizable.strings*

Following my naming convention I chose:

```
extension MyCoreDataEntity {
    func localizedActivityName() -> String {
         return NSLocalizedString("SomeKeyFor" + myCoreDataEntityProperty)
    }
}
```

Additional note, we can't guess if the translation exists (if you forgot one for instance or got a unmanaged on).
What we can do is the the translation value which should be the same one as the key if no translation was found. That's why having some convention for naming the key is also useful. Some starts them with `__ModuleWhereItSUsed_Key`, always in uppercase, etc.

```
extension MyCoreDataEntity {
    func localizedActivityName() -> String {
         let key =  "SomeKeyFor" + myCoreDataEntityProperty
         let translation =  NSLocalizedString("SomeKeyFor" + myCoreDataEntityProperty)
         if key == translation {
             return myCoreDataEntityProperty //Or "Unknown Activity", default value, etc.
         } else {
             return translation
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Right now inside core data 20 keys, but in couple days we will add another 130 keys, and perhaps in the future we will add more words.
It will be very difficult to maintain such code (with switch statement scenario).

Comment: Maybe name your var in localizables String in such a way that it's always the same pattern and it includes the "key" you put in the CoreData. From my example, it could be: `let localizableKey = "SomeKeyFor" + myCoreDataEntityProperty; return NSLocalizedString(localizableKey)`